# How to fill a graph by a color till a vertical line using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9jr1.jpg)I am trying to display vertical line in a line chart using chart.js. I am using the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mn8x6fso/) as a reference.

```
var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    var chart = this.chart;
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
    if (index) {
      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.top);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.bottom);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
      fill: false
    }],
    lineAtIndex: 2
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

In this I would like to pass the value to line At Index dynamically and also I would like to gray out the graph till that vertical line. For example if the line is at position 3, I want to apply some color till that position.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more understandable. I have included code sample from the fiddle. Please try to be more specific what you have already tryed. It can be useful to edit the sample to contain only relevant part of code. It can be also usefull to add an image of desired output.

Comment: Hi IvanH, thanks for editing my question. I have uploaded the image. I am able to display the both the line graphs but I am not sure how to scroll that vertical line using slider. I though of passing the slider value to lineAtIndex so that the vertical line will appear at that particular point. Kindly help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You can split the dataset into 2 and just set the fill property for the section with area to true, and the one without area to false. Your new dataset would appear as follows:

```js
datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [65, 0, 80],
      fill: true
    }, {
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [null, null, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
      fill: false
    }
]
```